# Are identical Quads actually equal?

Tags: lua, textures, love2d

Assume that a picture is divided to Quads of equal size with the `love.graphics.newQuad()` function. This picture has portions of identical color or pattern - for example when a QR code is read: it has euqally sized black and white parts.

If there's a `quad[1]` which is a black square, and a `quad[7]` which is also a black square but from another portion of the picture, then does the `quad[1] == [quad[7]` expression make sense?

To be short: are quads of (apparently) identical content **actually** identical, or is there a deeper difference that makes the expression above *always* `true` or `false`, regardless of similarity?

My question is not specified to QR codes but to any similar "pixelated" pictures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specialized code in Love2D that causes a deep test for object equality. An object is therefore only equal to *itself*. So every newly created object is a distinct value. Even if two objects happen to store the same internal data, they represent distinct objects as far as you can tell with `==`.